# Print elegantly in scientific notation python

Tags: python, number-formatting, scientific-notation

I wanna print a number and its uncertainty in the following way:

x = (4.23 ± 0.01) e3

where the value and its uncertainty are two different variables.

```
mean = 4230
uncertainty = 10 
print("x is %.2e \u00B1 %.2e" % (mean, uncertainty))
```

I want them to be formatted with the same power of the exponential in the scientific notation. what I get is

```
x is 4.23e+03 ± 1.00e+01
```

Comment: You will need to write your own custom logic for this, starting with code to discover the appropriate scale (e3 in your example, but what if the uncertainty is 1e6?).  Please try writing the code and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: If you're just looking for nicer formatting of your scientific notation, you could consider using this library when outputting your values.

https://github.com/David-OConnor/scinot

Answer (score 0):

Assuming mean integer, a way to do it might be

```
>>> mean = 4230
>>> uncertainty = 10 
>>> pos_to_first = len(str(mean)) - 1
>>> f"({mean/10**pos_to_first} ± {uncertainty/10**pos_to_first}) E{pos_to_first}"
'(4.23 ± 0.01) E3'
```